# Changing dojo/dijit custom _Widget params

Tags: dojo

I'm creating a "wrapper" widget which is essentially a way of creating a custom widget rather than extending a certain widget.

I want to modify the `params` passed in the `constructor`

Example:

```
constructor : function(params) {
    // do stuff
    params['id'] += '-container';
}
```

The problem is that in the next step of the `_Widget` lifecycle, `create` or `postMixInProperties`, the id will be back to it's originally passed in value...

EDIT:
I'm trying to modify the given `id` for the parent widget which will be a "container" of multiple other widgets.  I want to use the given id on one of those specific child widgets.  By the time the widget lifcycle gets to `postCreate` the dijit has already been registered.

Alternatively if I can't modify the params from the constructor, what would be a good way to override the `create` method to modify the arguments and call the remaining functions in the lifecycle?

Comment: Why not overwrite the `postCreate` function and set the `id` there?

Comment: So the widget with the constructor defined above is a widget that will create another widget, or.. something else? Would probably need some more context as to what you're trying to do, as is quite confusing as is

Comment: I'm trying to modify the given `id` for the parent widget which will be a "container" of multiple other widgets.  I want to use the given id on one of those specific child widgets.  By the time the widget lifcycle gets to `postCreate` the dijit has already been registered.